# How to access a kubernetes service through https?

Tags: kubernetes

This is my cluster info

```
kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://129.146.10.66:6443
Heapster is running at https://129.146.10.66:6443/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
KubeDNS is running at https://129.146.10.66:6443/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
```

So, I have a service(mysqlbrokerservice) running as NodePort and the configuration looks like this

```
kubectl describe svc mysqlbrokerservice
Name:                        mysqlbrokerservice
Namespace:                mysqlbroker
Labels:                        <none>
Annotations:                <none>
Selector:                app=mysqlbroker
Type:                        NodePort
IP:                        10.99.194.191
Port:                        mysqlbroker        8080/TCP
NodePort:                mysqlbroker        30000/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.1.198:8080
Session Affinity:        None
Events:                        <none>
```

I can access the service through the public IP of the node where the pod is running like this http://129.146.34.181:30000/v2/catalog.

Then what I wanted to see if I can access the service through https. I followed the direction  in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls

I followed the example and used curl to get the resource.
Here is the command. 129.146.10.66:6443 is my master ip.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET  https://129.146.10.66:6443/api/v1/namespaces/mysqlbroker/services/mysqlbrokerservice:8080/proxy/v2/catalog --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
```

curl just sits there with no response. I then looked at my pod logs and it does not show that any request received.

Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong here? What's the ideal solution if I want a service to be exposed through https?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this question? Is it possible to share?

Answer (score 1):

If you click any of the URLs provided by `kubectl cluster-info` you will see that your browser prompts you to accept an insecure TLS connection.

For HTTPs to work for this particular address you will need to buy a TLS certificate issued for the hostname (in this case, the IP address and you can't buy certs for IP addresses). The other option to add Kubernetes cluster's Root Certificate to your computer's Trusted Roots, but that wouldn't make it work on other computers.

So I assume you're just trying to make an application running on Kubernetes accessible to the outside world, via HTTPs:

For that, I recommend actually buying a domain name (or reusing a subdomain), buying a SSL/TLS certificate for that host name, and using an Ingress to configure a load balancer with HTTPs termination. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls (If you're on GKE, Google Load Balancer, otherwise it would configure a local nginx instance to do this task.)

Comment: But I can't even reach the service. Buying a trusted certificate and a domain is when I want it to be setup outside of my dev environment. Kubernetes has a self-signed certificate and I can use that for now. The issue I was pointing out to is how I can even reach the service from outside through the master as the way it's done e.g. kub-dns service.

Comment: are you able to look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61914106/how-can-i-create-a-helm-https-service ? + for the reference to the kubernetes root certificate.

Comment: There should be a way to make it work without a certificate in dev environment

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says it's expecting the port name and not number. Have you tried the following?

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET  https://129.146.10.66:6443/api/v1/namespaces/mysqlbroker/services/mysqlbrokerservice:mysqlbroker/proxy/v2/catalog --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
```

Comment: are you able to have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61914106/how-can-i-create-a-helm-https-service