# How can I create a HELM https service?

Tags: visual-studio, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I open Visual Studio 2019 and create a new project (Container application for kubernetes).  I tick enable https support and then when I start debugging in Visual Studio; I can browse to the https address.

I then try to go one step further.  I have Kubernetes enabled in Docker Desktop on my development PC and follow these instructions (after opening all the .yaml files and changing all references of https to http and all references of port 80 to port 443):

```
1) cd C:\mvcsecure
2) docker build -t mvcsecure:stable -f c:\mvcsecure\mvcsecure\Dockerfile .
3) cd c:\mvcsecure\mvcsecure\charts
4) helm install mvcsecure ./mvcsecure/
5) kubectl expose deployment mvcsecure --type=NodePort --name=mvcsecure-service
6) kubectl get service
mvcsecure-service   NodePort    10.96.128.133    <none>        443:31577/TCP   6s
7) I then try to browse to: https://localhost:31577 and it says: 
Cannot securely connect to this page
```

[image]

Notice there is no option to trust a certificate or anything.

What changes must I make to the default Helm charts created by Visual Studio to get https working on my basic service? I cannot find any documentation or examples online.  It would be great to see an example of a https service (mvc or api) deployed to Kubernetes using Helm.  I could post the .yaml file code if needed,, however there is a lot of it.

I am wanting to use kubernetes cluster root certificate as described here:  [How to access a kubernetes service through https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708272/how-to-access-a-kubernetes-service-through-https)

I have checked that all TLS and SSL options are ticked in Internet Options.

Comment: Hi, You wrote that You changed protocol references from `https` to `http` in the yaml files. Why?

Comment: @Piotr Malec, to be honest I am just leaning and not sure I am doing it right.  I asked another question here, which may make more sense: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917347/how-can-i-make-sure-my-website-is-secure-using-kubernetes-and-envoy

Answer (score 1):

In case when Your application accepts `HTTP` traffic and You want to make is secure (`HTTPS`); I suggest to try [TLS termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy) with kubernetes ingress.

Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls) has great explanation how to configure TLS termination. With ingress object You can make Your `HTTP` service be accessible via `HTTPS` from outside of the cluster.

This means that connections made to service will be made in `HTTPS` and get decrypted to `HTTP` once internally in Your cluster before reaching the service.

Hope it helps.